# HashMap is returning NULL

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Class Levels which has a hashMap declared.

```
public class Levels{
   private final Map<Unit, Object1> rateUnitCost;

   public Levels(Map<Unit, Object1> levels) {
  this.rateUnitCost = new HashMap<Unit, Object1>(levels);
 }

  public Object1 getCoverageLevel(Unit unit, Phase aP) {

        return rateUnitCost.get(unit);
        }
 }
```

I am calling getCoverageLevel() method from other class and i am instantiating the Levels class rateUnitCost property as well from another class.

When seeing in debugger i am finding this value for rateUnitCost and unit object.
rateUnitCost: -  Hash Map Values

```
  rateUnitCost  HashMap<K,V>  (id=1248) 
     [0]    HashMap$Node<K,V>  (id=1266)    
   key >Unit  (id=1249) 
        amount  Money  (id=1267)    
        flags   ArrayList<E>  (id=1268) 
        procedureId 7156    
        ParticipationId 104152413   
  value >Object1  (id=1250)
```

Now value of unit object is below :-

```
unit    Unit  (id=1251) 
amount  Money  (id=1258)    
flags   ArrayList<E>  (id=1259) 
procedureId 7156    
ParticipationId 104152413
```

when i match the value of key with this object then its matching .
But at the time of rateUnitCost.get(unit) its returning null even though Object1 is set. Object1 is getting returned from other class using below line: -

```
return new Object1();
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this mystery.?

BasicUnit is a class which is implementing the Unit interface. BasicUnit have equals method as below :-

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this == o) return true;
  if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

  BasicUnit basicUnit = (BasicUnit) o;

  if (flags != basicUnit.flags) return false;
  if (procedureId != basicUnit.procedureId) return false;
  if (ParticipationId != basicUnit.ParticipationId) return false;
  if (amount != null ? !amount.equals(basicUnit.amount) : basicUnit.amount != null) return false;

  return true;
```

}

and HashCode :-

```
 public int hashCode() {
  int result = procedureId;
  result = 31 * result + ParticipationId;
  result = 31 * result + (amount != null ? amount.hashCode() : 0);
  result = 31 * result + (flags == null ? null : flags.hashCode());
  return result;
```

}

Comment: @Manish: Can you please paste Unit class implementation details? As Map is handled based on hashkey.

Comment: @PrakashBhagat Unit is just an interface

    public interface Unit extends Comparable<Unit> {
   
}

Comment: Then pls paste implementation class detail.

Comment: @PrakashBhagat  
BasicUnit is a class which is implementing the Unit interface. BasicUnit have equals method as below :- public boolean equals(Object o) { if (this == o) return true; if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false; BasicUnit basicUnit = (BasicUnit) o; if (flags != basicUnit.flags) return false; if (procedureId != basicUnit.procedureId) return false; if (ParticipationId != basicUnit.ParticipationId) return false; if (amount != null ? !amount.equals(basicUnit.amount) : basicUnit.amount != null) return false; return true; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (flags != basicUnit.flags) return false;
```

You are checking for whether your `Unit` objects have **exactly** the same `ArrayList` of flags. This is not an `equals()`-type equality check; this is checking for literally the same `ArrayList` of flags. Now, you haven't provided the constructor etc, but I highly doubt you are reusing the same `ArrayList`.

Check for `!(flags.equals(basicUnit.flags))` instead.  Do note that `ArrayList.equals()` uses the `E.equals()` implementation, so be sure that that is implemented.

Also, note that `ArrayList.equals()` checks for the same list entries *in the same order*. I don't know if the order of your flags matters but I suspect it probably does not. You might consider making your flag collection a `Set` if this is the case.